# get a facebook authentication for a page

Tags: facebook, authentication

i am trying to catch the posts of a certain page using the open graph of facebook using https://graph.facebook.com/175119619168907/posts?access_token=access_token.

i was wondering do i have to create a new token for each user that goies to my page then he needs to add my app to his app lists? or can i create a token that does not expire and which i can use for all the users taht logs in? there is no security issue here since the user can only read posts and not write/comment.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution that you have to create an app token using the following url:

```
GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
           &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
           &grant_type=client_credentials
```

this token will not expire